# Is it possible to use otf fonts with cidfmap?

Tags: java, fonts, ghostscript, cjk

I am using 9.18 version of ghostscript. Is it possible to substitute opentype CID fonts? Can i mention it in CIDFMAP similar to mentioning truetype fonts as mentioned below

```
/Batang << /FileType /TrueType /Path (C:/WINDOWS/fonts/batang.ttc) /SubfontID 0 /CSI [(Korea1) 3] >> ;
```

Is there a different method to do so?

Answer (score 0):

This was opened as this bug report:

https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=700363

and then closed as invalid. I presume this means that the bug reporter was satisfied there was not a problem, and by implication that the question here is no longer relevant.

To answer the question; no there is no other method for defining CIDFonts for Ghostscript to use, except of course embedding them in the input. Note that at the time of writing, the current version of Ghostscript is 9.26, not 9.18 which is three years old at this point.